# How can I get mouseClick to find a variable and randomize it?

Tags: javascript, processing.js

Im working my way through the Khanacademy site and a a bit confused on how to make randomly sized(within certain parameters), and colored fish after mouseClick. I cant even get mouseClick working.

```
background(89, 216, 255);


var mouseClicked = function(drawFish){

};
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   What am I missing here? ^^^^^^^^^^

```
var drawFish = function(centerX, centerY, bodyLength, bodyHeight, bodyColor, tailWidth,
tailHeight, eyeColor,tailColor, eyeWidth, eyeHeight){


noStroke();
fill(bodyColor);
// body
ellipse(centerX, centerY, bodyLength, bodyHeight);
// tail

fill(tailColor);
triangle(centerX-bodyLength/2, centerY,
     centerX-bodyLength/2-tailWidth, centerY-tailHeight,
     centerX-bodyLength/2-tailWidth, centerY+tailHeight);
// eye
fill(eyeColor);
ellipse(centerX+bodyLength/3, centerY, eyeWidth, eyeHeight);

};
drawFish(296, 281, -57,52, color(245, 227, 30),-15, 60,color(13, 12,   12),color(66, 58, 58),4,4); // yellowFish

drawFish(290, 80, 180, 140, color(255, 0, 0), 57, 45,color(46, 66, 194), color(255, 204, 0),32,8); // redFish

drawFish(146,233, 218, 141, color(62, 110, 67), 30, 10, color(245, 240, 245), color(0, 51, 255),12,48); // greenFish

drawFish(233, 370, 322, 36, color(133, 34, 199), 61,15, color(255, 0, 0), color(34, 255, 0),67,20); // purpFish
```

Any other pointers or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks guys!

Comment: also, how would i go about  animating a fish? I know it would be somewhere along the lines of 'drawfish+=1" but how would I single out one of these fish when they all have the same call function name?

Comment: This is neither Processing code, nor JavaScript, you've created a mishmash of the two languages of which parts happen to do things and parts don't. I'd recommend not trying to shortcut things and just write Processing code at first. The API is well documented, and even just reading up the docs for `mouseClicked` will show you exactly why what you wrote doesn't work (hint: what you wrote does not match the API signature)

Answer (score 0):

Cool fishes!  I'm learning Processing too.  I ran your code and came up with this function for having random fishes appear when you click.

```
void mouseReleased() {
    var c1 = color(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255))
    var c2 = color(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255))
    var c3 = color(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255))
    var s1 = random(10,100)
    var s2 = random(10,100)
    var s3 = random(10,100)
    var s4 = random(10,100)
    var s5 = random(5,s1)
    var s6 = random(5,s2)
    drawFish(mouseX, mouseY, s1, s2, c2, s3,s4, c2, c3,s5,s6); //randFish
    }
```

[image]

To make an animation, I think you will want to use the draw() function, use variables for the x,y locations and redraw the background each time.  This example has the red fish follow the mouse around.

```
void draw(){
    background(89, 216, 255);
    drawFish(mouseX, mouseY, 180, 140, color(255, 0, 0), 57, 45,color(46, 66, 194), color(255, 204, 0),32,8); // redFish
    }
```

[image]

I hope your aquarium comes out really great!